# Is there any way to create partial index in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

I want to create partial index for the collection, but the index should be applied to documents by conditions. For example, I want to check uniqueness of documents only if they have the certain field value. In other words, I'm looking for some construction of index creating:

```
db.person.createIndex( 
  { age: 1}, 
  { partialFilterExpression: { age: { $gte: 18 }}
);
```

This example is from MongoDB and it is applying index on documents with field 'age' value greater then 18

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a "filtered index" (like you can in SQL).  According to the [docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/http/indexes.html), you can include attributes, but not conditionally.

You could try a sparse index, but I think your best bet is adding the `age` attribute to a ["skiplist"](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.7/http/indexes-skiplist.html) index, which supports sorting and `gt`/`lt` evaluation.

Make sure you use the `explain` feature to [validate index usage](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/indexing-working-with-indexes.html#revalidating-whether-an-index-is-used).